# binding datatable to calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

just want to ask how can  to bind dataTable to asp.net calendar I tried to but failed when the page load  I create sude code to exp lane what I want

```
    private void populateCalendar(DataTable dt)
    {

        foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
        {    //if dates are in dt chage background color to red 
            if(Calendar1.date)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added some code to my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your question, i tried to solve your query as

Step1: drag drop calender control in your markup

```
  <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1"  runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>
```

Step 2: on Calendar1_DayRender

```
   protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today);
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(10));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(12));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(8));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(6));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(9));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
            dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(3));
            DateTime date = e.Day.Date;
            var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where row.Field<DateTime>("date") == date
                   select row;
            foreach (var d in query)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }

    }
```

Note: DataTable used in my example is collection of dates

Comment: that's what I want but how can you change date range background color  if your dt has start_date and end_date

Comment: you can customize by using where row.Field<DateTime>("date")>=start_date && row.Field<DateTime>("date")<= endDate